# C#: comparing datetimepicker with MS access date

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

I am using ms access as database that contains field identified as (short date)
i inserted time to that field from datetimepicker in C# using the following query:

```
string query = @"insert into category_in  (category_id,amount_in,dates) 
               values ('" + ids + "','" + amount2 + "','"+dateTimePicker1.Text+"')";
```

and everything is ok. But when i am trying to compare the date in the database with date from another datetimpicker it doesnot work. This is the query of comparsion:

```
query = "SELECT products.category, category_in.dates FROM products, category_in where " + 
        "category_in.dates>= " + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortTimeString() + " "
        "and category_in.dates<= " + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToShortTimeString() + "";
```

when i use dateTimePicker.value.Date it gives me the following error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'category_in.dates>= 16/08/2015 12:00:00 ص and category_in.dates<=
>   20/08/2015 12:00:00 ص

but when i add dateTimePicker.value.Date.ToShortTimeString no results returned although there are some data between these dates

do i have to change the insertion method?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not work..."

Comment: i means that when i use dateTimePicker.value.Date it gives me that error
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'category_in.dates>= 16/08/2015 12:00:00 ص and category_in.dates<= 20/08/2015 12:00:00 ص
 but when i add dateTimePicker.value.Date.ToShortTimeString no results returned although there are some data between these dates

Comment: If I recall, you must surround date values with "#" in MS Access queries. And I don't think you want a shortTimeString, you want a Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should use the # delimiter for date expressions in Access:

```
string query = @"insert into category_in (category_id,amount_in,dates) 
               values ('" + ids + "','" + amount2 + "',#" + DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#)";
```

and:

```
query = "SELECT products.category, category_in.dates FROM products, category_in where " + 
        "category_in.dates >= #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# "
        "and category_in.dates <= #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that all three answers (so far) have suggested that you continue using dynamic SQL and fiddle with your string-formatted dates and delimiters until you get something that works.

That's just dumb.

The DateTimePicker control returns a `System.DateTime` value so you should just use that as part of a *parameterized query*, something like this:

```cs
using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(
        @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
        @"Dbq=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"))
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (DateTimeField) VALUES (?)", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to this:

```
query = "SELECT products.category, category_in.dates FROM products, category_in where " + 
        "category_in.dates>= #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# "
        "and category_in.dates<= #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#";
```

Comment: thank you but it still gives me exception and the date is shown as:
category_in.dates>= #20/08/2015 12:00:00 am#
while the format i need is only 20/08/2015

Comment: Is it the same exception? Try hard-coding a known good date value in the query instead of getting from the date picker just to narrow down the problem then change it back to dynamic when you get the syntax correct.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Why are you converting to ShortTimeString() ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is your dates are strings.  Add Single quotes before and after your datetime values.  Like this...

```
query = "SELECT products.category, category_in.dates FROM products, category_in where " + 
        "category_in.dates>= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortTimeString() + "' "
        "and category_in.dates<= '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToShortTimeString() + "'";
```

This will allow the query engine to implicitly convert the strings to datetimes.